# Error receiving broadcast Intent act=com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASES_UPDATED

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

I'm getting an error in crashlytics logs

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASES_UPDATED flg=0x10 pkg=*** (has extras) } in com.android.billingclient.api.zzg@c300e4d android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1577) android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2) android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:368) android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7710) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)

Using standard Google billing library subscriptions + in-app billing

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate

I don't see in docs that I should register broadcast receiver, where `PURCHASES_UPDATED` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was an architectural issue, the billing client was initialized in some base `Activity` in `onCreate`, and there was a situation when purchase callback was triggered in few activities, and one of them was in illegal state.

Comment: Where should we init our billing client if not in an activity?

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi I'm wrapping billing client in separate class and with the help of dagger/hilt make him single instance, and initialize the billing client in application `onCreate`

Answer (score -1):

Interesting, I fixed the location of the checkout links when I pulled the onresume for the trailer. formerly oncreateview was using my billing code

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33569627)

Comment: This answer did not make sense at all